# How to convert images into @2x

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone apps. I want to know steps for converting
normal(size) ratio images into @2x double size images. Thanks in
advance.

Comment: Are you asking about assesses included with your app? Or are you asking about images that the app handles?

Answer (score 3):

What part has you confused?

1. Generate a piece of art for your app that fits into a 960x640 (or 640x960) UI design
2. Save it as `myimage@2x.png`
3. Shrink it's dimensions exactly in half (i.e. from 200x150 to 100x75)
4. Save as `myimage.png`
5. Import both into your project.
6. Select `myimage.png` in an IB file or use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"]` to load your image.

Pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for given your reply, but when Can I use myimage@2x.png image in my app?

Comment: Uh, sure you can.  That's uh the whole point.  Again, what part has you confused?

Comment: In Android the 9.png image develop  by using the 9patch tool, but in iPhone how can I develop?